# PDF attributes AL

Tags: pdf

What does AL attribute stand for in PDF document? Found in Properties>details

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: Can you also add a screenshot showing where you see this "AL attribute", and make sure the application being used is clearly indicated in the screenshot.